Deduce irreducible representation matrices from the regular representation
I am currently reading chapter 3 from the book Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics by Michael Tinkham.
I came across the regular representation $\Gamma^{(reg)}$, more specifically the celebrated theorem:

The regular representation contains each irreducible representation a number of times equal to the dimensionality of the irreducible representation.

This theorem got me thinking. If one sets up the matrices for the regular representation as explained in the book (by means of the multiplication table). Is it then possible to deduce the matrices for the irreducible representations?
I believe there might be an issue concerning the fact that the matrices for the regular representation are not necessarily in block form. So then my follow-up question is: Is it possible to find the similarity transformation that retreives the block form for the regular representation matrices?

Yes of course it is possible. But I don't think this leads to an efficient algorithm. Finding matrices for the irreducible representations is not easy in general, and some of  the methods used in practice make use of the character table of the group, which is easier to calculate.

Do you maybe have some sources that discuss methods to find the matrices for the irreducible representations using the character table?

There's a paper 1970  by J.D. Dixon, "Computing Irreducible Representations of Groups", which you can find online, and which has been used as a basis of implementations (in GAP for example).

Thank you, Derek!
